# Need advice on best practice(s) for using databases in my ASP.NET website

Tags: asp.net

I'm building a website that will be used by employees to log work that they've completed. The site contains a page to submit the information, a page to view the information and a page with the employees personal info like name, email, phone, etc. I'm using ASP.NET Membership for authentication. All code will be VB. My questions:

1) ASP.NET Membership only stores the username and email of members. I want to store additional information like first and last name, phone number, etc. Can I just update the tables in the membership database to include this information? Or should I store this information in a separate database? My goal is to populate text boxes on one of the pages with data specific to the user that is currently logged in.

2) The work completed will be stored in another database since it seems logical to keep it separate from membership data. What is the most efficient way to pull and display records from this separate "work" database that are specific to the user who has logged in and been authenticated against the member database?

3) I'm having trouble with the design of tables for the "work" database. Each record stored in the database will represent a days worth of work. However, a number of activities will occur during that day. Each activity will have a type of activity, location and amount of time worked. An employee can complete 1 activity or 100 activities. I assume I'm going to need a table just for the activities and then relate it to the work table. Does this sound correct?

Comment: You could use the builtin [Profile provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs(v=vs.100).aspx) to add additional informations like image,phone number,first/last-name etc.

Answer (score 1):

For your first Point i will suggest you to create your own table of User and relate this table with membership user table with guid viz. keep on userid file in your table and relate it with membership table.

Second point will automatically get solved once you will create your own user table, all you need is to relate work and user table(created by you) to fetch the records from work

And at last if you are creating new table for activities how come you will relate it to your work table, again you will have multiple occurrence for record, instead i would suggest do not create another table for activities keep it in work table itself as if you are creating a new table, you will have to provide relationship with work which will result in redundancy.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the reply! For each user, there will be one entry per day into the work table. (The work entries are basically daily reports) For each work entry, there is an indeterminate number of activities completed. (Could be anywhere from 1 to 100 different activities all with user generated explanations.) Since I don't know how many activities there will be, I wouldn't know how many columns to add to the work table. I'd have to add enough columns to the work table to cover the maximum possible number of activities, which is unknown. This just seems inefficient/redundant to me.

Comment: Thats why I was thinking of creating a table just for the activities and having a one-to-many relationship with the work table. This way, my table structure would be clean and simple with no guessing/over-compensating on the number of activities. The activities would be inserted into the table only as needed.

Comment: In such case it would be better to have different table, but if your relationship with work and activities does not make sense dan it would be better to have only one table.